# Xamarin.IOS Toggle Button?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is there toggle button for xamarin.ios? If not, the better aproach is work with two buttons and toggle their Hidden property?

Thank you

Comment: Are you referring to the UISwitch? http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UISwitch/

Comment: Yes, but I dont wanna the switch layout. I waan it to be a play-pause button but when I set the images for on-off it wont show, it still looks the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        UIButton btnPlayAndStop = new UIButton (new CGRect (100, 100, 50, 50));
        btnPlayAndStop.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
        btnPlayAndStop.Tag = 0;
        btnPlayAndStop.SetImage (UIImage.FromFile ("play.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
        btnPlayAndStop.TouchUpInside += delegate {
            if (0 == btnPlayAndStop.Tag) { 
                btnPlayAndStop.Tag = 1;
                btnPlayAndStop.SetImage (UIImage.FromFile ("stop.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            }
            else if (1 == btnPlayAndStop.Tag) {
                btnPlayAndStop.Tag = 0;
                btnPlayAndStop.SetImage (UIImage.FromFile ("play.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            }
        };
        this.View.AddSubview (btnPlayAndStop);
    }
```

Hope it can help you.

Any problem about Xamarin.iOS is welcome.